# javax mail exceeding sending limit : SMTPSendFailedException

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send 500+ emails via a for loop with javaxmail - no Spam, the email adresses are known and certified.

The aim was to have a little time delay (1 - 5 sec) between sending (Thread.sleep(...)), so the mails do not automatically go into the Spam Folder. But after testing some time by sending it to my own email address, I keep getting this error :

> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 554 5.7.0 Your message
>   could not be sent. The limit on the number of allowed outgoing
>   messages was exceeded. Try again later.

I am using our own smtp Server.

```
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");
```

I'd like to know how long the time span for "try again later" is?

Does anyone know the limit?

Also any suggestions how to avoid this would be helpful.

Comment: The 554 error is returned by the _recipient_'s SMTP server which has a spam filter of some sort.

Comment: I think you need to consult the documentation for your own SMTP server for the answer to this one.  In reality though you won't be sending 500 emails to one inbox so you probably wouldn't have this problem in reality...  Also, are all the emails the same?

Comment: the mails have a personal greeting in the message but otherwise they are the same. I tried sending to all emailadresses but still get the error after some hundred mails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most of the cases you should try to avoid those mass mail sending (spam filters are pretty discriminative on large amount of mails no matter what), but in your case there is a simpler answer. Distributed mail processing is preferred, with time based limit rates etc.

The problem You likely have is that (as the errormsg says) you try to exceed the limit of your outgoing mail number. (You could get further information by examining the [getCommand and getReturnCode](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPSendFailedException.html#getCommand--).) If you are using POSTFIX with policyd here is an example of the outgoing mail limit configuration:

> http://wiki.policyd.org/accounting?s[]=limit

You could "fix" this problem by reconfiguring your SMTP server. Altough my recommendation is (to avoid getting on block list) to **split up your** whole **email sending process**:

- create a(n hourly?) cron job that invokes a mail sender process
- in the process you should have a limit (eg: 100) and try to send the mails
- if the mail is sent it is OK else the next time the cron is running you could try to resend it (use a maximum number for retry with some log information)

*Those limits are for your own safety* in most of the cases. Those prevent you from getting onto blacklists if a software bug occures etc.

Answer (score 1):

### If you exceed a users email sending limits, you may see an error message such as:

- 5.7.0 Your message could not be sent. The limit on the number of allowed outgoing messages was exceeded. Try again later.
- Sorry, your message has too many recepients.

To keep systems healthy and your accounts safe, there is a limit amount of mail, a user can send. Limits restrict the number of messages sent per hour and the number of recipients per message. After reaching one of these limits, a user can't send new messages, but they can still access their account and receive incoming email.

### Current Email Limits

- Up to 150 messages per hour.
- Up to 99 recipients per message.

Various ISP provider gives a limit. You can take a look from here: [SMTP Sending Limit and Email Rate Limits for ISPs - Verizon, Comcast, EarthLink, etc](http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/tips/email-rate-limit.html).

In [Plesk Documentation](http://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/administrator-guide/mail/protection-from-outbound-spam/custom-limits.73368/), you will get `Custom Limits for Service Plans`, `Limits for Subscriptions`, `Limits for Domains` and `Limits for Mailboxes` .

> 100 messages will be sent successfully, but starting from 101 message
>   for the same hour Webmail will show the following error.

### Resource Link:

[How outgoing messages limit works?](https://kb.plesk.com/en/128429)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a ton of people with the same issue, and a lot of information of many solutions tried. 
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/yrEDNJ3fChs

Also here is a link to a Bulk Senders Guidelines:
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en